# Modify the first related record in a changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Is there a way to change only the first item in a relationship via a changeset? Aka if I had:

- **1** `account` with **N** `emails`

s it possible to do something like:

```
schema "accounts" do 
    ...
    has_many(:emails, StockrtApi.Accounts.Email)
end

def changeset(account, params) do
    account
    ...
    |> cast_assoc(:emails, required: true, with: &Email.changeset(&1, &2))
    |> put_change(first_email_only, {primary: true}) # <- might have to go in email schema
end
```

Or what's the best way to approach this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

One should not rely on the order of anything when dealing with databases (unless an explicit `ORDER BY` clause is presented.) While most database drivers will return a predictably ordered set without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, it *is by no means guaranteed*. That said, it’s always better to prefer *explicity over implicity*: just introduce another `through` association:

```rb
schema "accounts" do 
  ...
  has_many :emails, StockrtApi.Accounts.Email
  has_one :primary_email, through: [:primary_email, :email]
end
```

And put this association with a usual [`Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4).

---

As per a comment, when all you need is to ensure there is an email, do exactly this:

```rb
defp ensure_email(
  %Ecto.Changeset{errors: errors, changes: %{emails: emails}} = changes
) do
  case emails do  
    [] ->
      new_errors = [{:emails, {"can’t be empty", [validation: :emails]}}]
      %{changes | errors: new_errors ++ errors, valid?: false}
    _ -> changes
  end
end
```

and use it explicitly:

```rb
def changeset(account, params) do
  account
  ...
  |> cast_assoc(:emails, required: true, with: &Email.changeset(&1, &2))
  |> ensure_email()
end
```

That way you ensure that at least one email is present—just use the first one as `primary`.

Comment: I'm not actually concerned about order per-say, I'm just trying to ensure that when I insert an for the first time (aka someone signs up) that 1 of their emails is set to primary (and only 1). But based on your comment, I think this logic would be more appropriate in the context? Or maybe the account schema?

Comment: If you are not concerned about the order, I do not see any reason in having this association at all. Just ensure the `:emails` assoc is not empty.

Comment: Updated the answer.